# Google Group Migration API "Failed to upload message due to backend error" error while migrating an email

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-groups-migration

I have been trying to migrate all my emails to a group. I use nodejs google library and I'm the owner of the group.
I can migrate between 30 and 40 emails but after of this I have an error where I migrating.
I have the next error:

`{
  error: {
    code: 500,
    message: 'Unknown Error.',
    errors: [ [Object] ],
    status: 'UNKNOWN'
  }
}`

and when I go to see the attribute errors I have the next error:`[ { message: 'Failed to upload message due to backend error' } ]`

This is my code to migrate:

```
 const res = await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/groups/v1/groups/${email}/archive?uploadType=media`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body:    message,
                headers: { 
                    'Content-Type': 'message/rfc822' ,
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${oauth2Client.credentials.access_token}`
                },
            });
            const json = await res.json();
            if(json) console.log(json.error.errors);
```

Any help or ideas will be highly appreciated

Comment: Same issue.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: The problem in my case is that I send a lot of mails at same time try to migrate 1 by 1

Comment: I was initially trying to send a lot at once, but I changed it to go one at a time and I'm still getting an error.

Mine does actually differ from yours slightly, in the errors array I just get an empty object (not the backend error message).

Comment: Sorry but in my case sending 1 a 1 I solved the problem good luck with the problem